# Issues with v$archived_log - Oracle 19c

Tags: recovery, oracle-19c, standby, archive-log

I have a standby database, on which I executed the command:

```
alter database recover managed standby database cancel
```

and it was executed successfully - The complication I am facing is:

When I execute:

```
select max(sequence#) Max_Applied from v$archived_log where applied = 'YES';
```

for some reason, it shows that my standby is in synced the primary, but when I use this command:

```
SELECT name, standby_dest, MAX(SEQUENCE#) AS max_sequence, archived, applied, status
FROM v$archived_log
WHERE name LIKE '%name%' AND applied = 'YES'
GROUP BY name, standby_dest, archived, applied, status;
```

the archives are behind (which should be correct)

When I enabled the MRP process, in the alert logfile the archives, which were not applied according to

```
select max(sequence#) Max_Applied from v$archived_log where applied = 'YES';
```

start being applied...

Any help?